# AppDomainUnloadedException - how to debug?

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2010, azure

I am working with MS Windows Azure. When I start my program, I get an AppDomainUnloadedException before the first Code is reached.

How can I find out, what the actual problem is? What is missing?

Comment: Does this help at all: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/7c8967ba-694f-4125-9425-2962af74e974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new Visual Studio Project, moved all the code, linked the dlls new and then it worked. 
So it was no Coding problem, but an inconsistency in the VS project. 
Seems to happen sometimes, if projects are migrated from older VS versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you are trying to access some resources in a Role before the role has actually been activated.

What are you trying to run? I've run into this problem before when trying to createifnotexist a blob container or table in the Application_Start of the global.asax

With questions like these it is best to provide as much detail as you possibly can about what your code is attempting to achieve, it makes it much easier to help. Can you follow up with what your application is doing in order for me to try to get a more accurate answer?

Comment: No - the coding is correct. The problem is solved already. See above (fresh MS VS Project).